# Backbone MVP - Who attaches the view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mvp

So I am writing a Backbone.js application.
I have opted to use the MVP pattern with Passive Views.

Now my arch so far is:

- Application
- - Page Presenter
- - - Layout View
- - Header Presenter
- - - Layout View
- - - - Logo View
- - - - User View
- - Content Presenter
- - - Layout View
- - Footer Presenter
- - - Layout View

Now I am very new to the concept of MVP (had a lot of experience with MVC).

So say I want to render the header's layout and then attach it to the Page Presenter's layout view, who's responsibility is it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Most often, I see simple HTML/Image elements contained in a view template that is brought in via Handlebars, Underscore templating, or the like to the view.  This allows you to keep your javascript and html separated.  Absent that, HTML would live directly in the view.

The [examples in this article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvc-and-mvp-for-javascript-and-backbone-developers/) make a common pattern for templates in MVP pretty clear.

I prefer to go one step further in my apps, starting with a common template in index for things like logos, main page layout, etc....then drawing my views in an element of that common template assisted by specialized, smaller, templates-per-view that contain specific html content to make the view work.  The downside is that some template-per-views can be empty files, but that is a very rare occurance.  It's also quite clear to the rest of the team where an element is going to be if they need to edit it.